# How to force widgets to the right dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I use the library [ChipView](https://github.com/Plumillon/ChipView) and I have the following layout:

```
<com.plumillonforge.android.chipview.ChipView
    android:id="@+id/chip_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    chip:chip_background="@color/primaryColor"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

For some reason it does not detect that the app is in RTL language and it keeps the chips from left to right (instead of right to left). It's a third-party library so is there something I can do in order to make it detect RTL? I want it to be LTR in LTR mode and RTL in RTL mode and not to force it to be RTL always. If there is a need to change it dynamically, please show how to do it with Java.